# Counting edges in a specially defined graph

Tags: elementary-number-theory, graph-theory

$G$ has vertices $\{0, \ldots, pq - 1\}$, where $p, q$ are different primes. There is an edge between $x$ and $y$ if $p \mid x - y$ or $q \mid x - y$. How many edges does $G$ have?

I looked at the cases where $p=2$ and $q=3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 23$ and the formula I got was $|E|=q^2$, but it doesn't apply to $p=3$. For $p = 3, q = 5$, there are $45$ edges.

How do I derive a closed form formula for this?

Comment: Maybe think about the case that the are vertices $\{0,...,pq-1,pq\}$ first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the set $\{0,\dots,pq-1\}$, there are $p$ elements in each equivalence class modulo $q$, and $q$ in each class modulo $p$.

Since there is an edge between $x$ and $y$ iff $x\cong y \pmod p$ of $x\cong y \pmod q$, each of the $p$ equivalence classes modulo $p$ contributes $\frac{q(q-1)}2$ edges, and each of the q equivalence classes modulo $q$ contributes $\frac{p(p-1)}2$ edges.

Therefore, overall, there are $\frac{pq(q-1) + pq(p-1)}2$ edges.

In the case $p=2$, this does in fact simplify to $q^2$, as you found.